# Why does Drupal >= 9.4.7 not allow including .php files in Twig templates?

Tags: 9

I have been handed a site with an old custom theme purchased from a third party.

After the last drupal update - 9.4.8 - logged in users stopped being able to access the front end of the site. Administration pages were still accessible.

After some digging I found the error was this line in a twig template:

```
{% include directory ~ '/customize/form.php' %}
```

It was causing the following error:

```
Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "themes/gavias_tico/customize/form.php" is not defined in "themes/gavias_tico/templates/addon/skins.html.twig" at line 4. in Twig\Loader\ChainLoader->getCacheKey() (line 98 of /var/www/mysite.org.au/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/ChainLoader.php).
```

The template (php) file is present at the location listed so it appears twig is finding the correct path, however, the site is still WoD after this for logged-in users.

Has there been a change to the way twig includes should be done in drupal? How can I fix this?

Comment: Why would you include .php files in twig?

Comment: I wouldn't. I'm fixing someone else's codebase.

Comment: Further investigation makes me think the original theme authors were updating an old drupal 7 theme to work with d8/twig and rather than re-write everything they decided to import snippets of old template code written in php (it's mostly just html) into minimal twig files for compatibility.

Comment: Were you able to discover a solution? Did you rewrite everything, scrap the theme, or did you find a fix?

Comment: I renamed all the imported files and import statements. Luckily for me the problem files mostly just contained html. If you are dealing with old embedded php the re-factoring process could be more complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from Drupal 9.4.7 and [its release notes](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/9.4.7) explain:

“Following this release, by default, Twig may load the following file types:

- .css
- .html
- .js
- .svg
- .twig

If your site, module, or theme must load additional file types via Twig, consult the documentation for twig.config.allowed_file_extensions in default.services.yml.”

But allowing other types may be dangerous. Read the [security advisory](https://www.drupal.org/sa-core-2022-016) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I faced an same type of issue when updating the Drupal core from 9.4.5 to 9.4.8

**Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "themes/gavias_tico/customize/form.php" is not defined in "themes/gavias_tico/templates/addon/skins.html.twig" at line 4. in Twig\Loader\ChainLoader->getCacheKey() (line 98 of /var/www/mysite.org.au/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/ChainLoader.php).**

Based on the @cilefe, due to the security advisory only the following extensions are allowed to use in twig fix.

.css
.html
.js
.svg
.twig

Using php file in twig file is not allowed. I just changed the name of the file from yourfilename.php to yourfilename.html, and the same file called in the skins.html.twig

Hope this could helps to sort out this issue

Comment: Yes, that is more-or-less how I fixed the issue. But if you are dealing with a more complex  set of old theme files you might have to re-factor the actual files themselves. Since my question is about import behaviour i think @cilefen is the right answer and best starting point for other people with the issue. You're solution does work in many circumstances - including mine - though.